# QT5: static build under windows (openGL troubles)

Tags: qt, opengl-es, qt5

I'm trying to compile a QT from the source code under Windows using the script from the official instructions. (https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW)

```
cmd /c "configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -prefix $QtDir `
-qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sql-sqlite -no-openssl -opensource -confirm-license `
-make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests"
mingw32-make -k -j4
mingw32-make -k install
```

In the result I got two problems:

1) build options:

OpenGL:

- ANGLE ................................ **no**
- Desktop OpenGL ....................... no
- Dynamic OpenGL ....................... no
- OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ **yes**
- OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ no
- OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
- OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ no
- Vulkan ................................. no

2) fatal error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory

I tried to set all possible options for the "-opengl" parameter, none worked.

I have installed the directive which is required for ANGLE and the paths in PATH are written, but the installation still does not find it. Also, in the source directory, next to each file that requires GLES2, there are all necessary headers.

I tried to manually download the ANGLE library and write a path to it in PATH, but this did not work.

The same problems were describe in
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53752-Error-compiling-qt5-01-on-indovs
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59996

but the solutions did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Search for missing files in the qt folder, copy their parent folders such as GLES2 or KHR to MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include. It's just brutal force.